# argparse usage with options, not parameters

Tags: python, argparse

If I am passing an boolean option to my script, which is basically true if the option is supplied and false if not, how do I process it differently with `argparse` than a parameter that holds value.

For example, my script takes a parameter **propFile**, which holds a value and an option **clean**, which is just a true/false flag. The usage is

> myScript.py --propFile=path/to/my/prop.file -clean

Note that I try to differentiate between parameters and options on the user level by assigning two dashes to the former and a single dash to the latter, which shouldn't matter to the interpreter.

I want to assign `scrptVarClean=True` if `-clean` is provided and `False` if not.

What I tried is:

```
argparser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
argparser.add_argument('--propFile', help='Properties file path')
argparser.add_argument('-clean', help='Clean?')
args = argparser.parse_args();
propFile = args.props
clean = args.clean
```

but I got

> pgCloner.py: error: argument -clean: expected one argument

How can I use an optional boolean argument with argparse?

Comment: Note that it's conventional to use single dashes for short versions of flags (e.g. `-c` for `--clean`); although it doesn't matter to the interpreter, it may not be what consumers of your CLI expect.

Comment: I know but so, for the parameter arg, I just avoid providing a shorter version, to differentiate

Comment: That is what I read into *"I try to differentiate between parameters and options on the user level by assigning two dashes to the former and a single dash to the latter"*, I'm just saying: don't.

Comment: this kind of discussion on semantics is pretty pointless. you will never have a single convention just like the world will never speak only one langugage

Comment: There certainly won't be if people refuse to adopt the ones that already exist and insist on making up their own, but you do you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Value of `clean` will be `True` if "--clean" or "-c" is supplied, else `False`

```
parser.add_argument('-c', '--clean', action="store_true")
```

Comment: Beat me to it. Very nice.

Comment: Otherwise known as "read the [argparse docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#action)".

Comment: OP wanted single dash. Hope you don't mind the edits.

Comment: @MadPhysicist yeah I noticed, but that didn't seem good. Let's provide better option...

Comment: @jatinderjit. It's purely a matter of taste, and the OP's reasoning was sensible.

Comment: it's a matter of personal preferences, variations among which is reasonable as @MadPhysicist noted. trying to enforce a global standard on trivial conventions like this would be pedantic to say the least.